# How does Automatic Seeding work - Always On Availability Group

Tags: sql-server, backup, availability-groups, high-availability, enterprise-edition

I found only these two statements from BOL regarding this Initial Data Synchronization method:

[Link 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/automatic-seeding-secondary-replicas?view=sql-server-ver15)

> Automatic seeding uses the log stream transport to stream the backup
> using VDI to the secondary replica for each database of the
> availability group using the configured endpoints.

[Link 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/automatic-seeding-secondary-replicas?view=sql-server-ver15)

> During automatic seeding, SQL Server performs a backup over the
> network for initialization.

Looking into SQL Server Error logs of both primary and secondary replicas, these two logs caught my attention:

**On primary replica**

[image]

**On secondary replica**

[image]

My question is related to the working nature of automatic seeding, namely where does taken backup is stored before restoring on the secondary replica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noted, the docs refer to "log stream transport" when performing automatic seeding. Similar to the way that you can stream movies to your device without downloading a specific file, automatic seeding streams data to the secondary without storing an actual backup file.

While the technical implementation details aren't exactly this, it's essentially taking a backup, but rather than sending it to a storage device or file share, it sends it to the secondary server. Rather than writing a file, it immediately begins to restore to the secondary server. The pseudo-backup is buffered and restored in a single step, without a literal backup being written to file.